# Como eu substituo o DialogResul do windows form no wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

Tenho esse código:

```
DialogResult dr = ofd1.ShowDialog();
```

Passando para o WPF não funciona. Busquei na internet e não achei nada ainda, que me satisfaça. Como eu substituo no WPF?

Obs: ofd1 é um `OpenDialog`

Answer (score 0):

Use o [`MessageResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messageboxresult.aspx)

```
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Questão", "Título", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
    // Fazer algo
}
```

Comment: Esse exemplo eu já vi na internet e não consegui fazer funcionar por ele.

Comment: Não conseguiu o que? Fica difícil ajudar sem saber qual é o problema

Comment: Isso não funciona: ` MessageBoxResult dr = ofd1.ShowDialog();`

Comment: Você adicionou o namespace `System.Windows`?

Comment: O código acima que eu postei vem de um OpenDialog e aquela linha eu seleciono o arquivo que quero carregar. Com esse exemplo, eu não consigo abrir. Esse é o problema que eu estou tendo. Sim adicionei a linha. Não dá erro. Só não funciona como o esperado por essa questão.

Answer (score 0):

Assim funcionou:

```
Nullable<bool> result = ofd1.ShowDialog();

            if(result == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    LocalizacaoZip = ofd1.FileName;
                    nome_arquivo_zip = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ofd1.FileName);
                }
                catch (SecurityException ex)
                {

                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                { }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Como você faz a comparação do resultado do OpenFileDialog? O código abaixo funciona perfeitamente para mim..

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
    namespace TesteWpf {
        class Program {
            [STAThread]
            static void Main(string[] args) {

                using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog()) {
                    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {    
                    }
                }    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Para mim funciona no windows form, mas não funcionou no wpf.